# how to use codeigniter for application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter but I wanted to create an application like that of http://redbeacon.com or http://thumbtack.com.

What is the best approach to go about creating a site like one of the above and is there any open source application I can use as a skeleton? Even a tutorial on creating a site like that would be great!

Thank you so much!

Comment: hmm I'm assuming you have solid php/mysql experience?

Comment: @themerlinproject I have php/mysql exp. just unsure how advanced I would need to be as I haven't used CI before..

Comment: Codeigniter is a framwework.  You can make sites like you link to with straight php or with codeigniter. Anything you can do with php you can do with codeigniter, just easier.  You wont learn Codeigniter unless you dive in and start off. asking questions here is a great help when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there are any specific open source solutions to your particular problem so I would say that you're going to have to create most of the site from scratch.   That is, provided you have a good knowledge of PHP already.

If not, then I would suggest starting with some [good php development books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book) that will teach you the fundamentals of PHP.

For learning CodeIgniter you're quite lucky. One of the best parts about CodeIgniter is that it is [very well documented](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/toc.html).

Answer (score 1):

For the quickest ramp up time I would take a hard look at [Expression Engine](http://expressionengine.com/overview/). It is a commercial web publish tool that is based on CodeIgniter - so you get all the power of CI but with much greater ease of use.  You can make pretty much any kind of site/web app with EE: [showcase](http://expressionengine.com/showcase/).